# What kind of light bulb is Cooper R10 PLC-13W?

Tags: lighting, light-bulb

Seems like there are a lot of different types of bulbs like this one, but so many different specs. How do I go about replacing it? Various bulbs I am seeing on Amazon specifically say things like "Replaces Philips 38327-3, GE 97596 and Sylvania 20671". I am hoping that doesn't matter much and that I could just get some off Amazon rather than have to special-order them.

Edit: And are there adapters that let me use regular bulbs?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a 4-pin compact florescent lamp. Since it has a pin base instead of a screw base, the ballast is located in the fixture, not in the light.

Unfortunately, this fixture is not completable with anything but a florescent light or an LED light designed to replace one. It cannot be adapted to any other kind of light without modifying the fixture.

Comment: So are there compatibility issues with these or can I just get any "4-pin compact florescent lamp"?

Comment: @flemming The ballast in the fixture will be designed for a specific range of bulb wattages. To be safe, get a 13 Watt, 4-pin CF to match the old one.

Comment: Alright, I went ahead and ordered these:
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01GQV91OM

It has specs like "841" and "G24q-1", but, by your answer, doesn't seem like these matter. It also says "Replacement for Philips 38328-1 PL-C 13W/841/4P/ALTO, Sylvania 20667 and GE 97597 - F13DBX/841/ECO4P" which I also assume doesn't matter since this is a 13-watt, 4-pin CF/L. Will mark as answer after I confirm these work. Thanks.